# Link from one Git repository to another repository's folder

Tags: filesystems, git

I'm trying to add a reference from one Git repository to a specific folder from a remote repository.

Example:

repo-1

```
.
├── a
├── b
└── c
```

repo-2

```
.
├── A
├── B      # this should link to repo-1's `b` folder
└── C
```

Edit 1: To clarify, I'm using Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with git.

Each commit reference is a pointer to a snapshot of the entire tracked file system and so any linking would be to the entire repository and not a portion of it.

The work around would be to make 'folder' b it's own seperate repository.  You would then include this in repo-1 and repo-2 as a submodule.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules explains submodules in detail.